# Specified cast is not valid linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Below code throws exception while casting.

```
  Dim objRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = (From myRow As DataRow In objDS.Tables(0).AsEnumerable Select myRow.Field(Of Int64)(Person_Id) Distinct).Cast(Of DataRow)()
```

All worked fine until the project warning settings were updated to warning for implicit conversion and implicit type,object assumed.

Now i have to declare objects types and that's breaking every linq. Does linq work with these settings?

Stack trace

at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

problem is at :  System.Linq.Enumerable.d__81`1 Not sure what is this 81 that it is not liking

Comment: You select a certain value from your data rows by using `Select myRow.Field(Of Int64)(Person_Id) Distinct`. The query doesn't return a list of data rows, so you cannot cast it to that. Rather declase `objRows As IEnumerable(Of Int64)`.

Comment: How is this different from the question you asked half an hour ago and have marked as answered?

Comment: Yes i have , Now it is throwing a different exception but resolves the first one. I have multiple rows of same PersonId and want a list of all distinct  Personid.

Comment: Tried following still doesn't work : Dim distinctValues As List(Of Int64) = (From r In _
   objDS.Tables(0) Where (Not r.IsNull(person_Id)) _
  Select r.Field(Of Int64)(person_Id)).Distinct().ToList()

Comment: Maybe the field isn't `Int64`, but `Int64?` ?

Comment: Tried that as well still no luck :(

Comment: Right the Type for personId is Decimal, Don't understand How this worked perfectly fine while using the same code with project settings warnings to none :(